# Zipping RDD's with same number of elements, but throws errors that "Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to zip two rdd's that have the same number of elements. But when calling zip I get an error that the rdd's do not contain the same number of elements. The specific error is, "Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition".

```
    data = data.sortBy(lambda x: x[0]).zip(tod).map(lambda x: (x[0][0], x[0][1], x[0][4], x[0][5], x[0][6], x[1][1], x[1][2], x[1][3], x[1][4], x[1][5], x[1][6],  x[0][7]))

    bool_converted = data.map(lambda x: convertStringToFloat(x[0], x[4])).sortBy(lambda x: x[0])
```

Then I call

```
    data = data.zip(bool_converted)
```

Which throws the error

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 22.0 (TID 86)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition
```

But I have the same number of elements in the partitions:

```
    print("data", data.count())
    print("bool_converted", bool_converted.count())
```

Which gives:

```
('data', 1458644)
('bool_converted', 1458644)
```

I even checked the number of partitions. Both are 8.

Can anyone explain what is going on and how to prevent this?

Comment: *follow* - same issue here